# Liveview resizing iFrames’s heights to fit contents by obtaining the scrollHeight

Tags: iframe, phoenix-live-view

I need to resizing iFrames’s heights to fit contents by obtaining the scrollHeight. I created a Phoenix Liveview JS Hook and used it in heex template.

```html
<iframe 
  srcdoc={@email.body} 
  class="w-full" 
  id={"email-#{@email.id}"} 
  phx-hook="Iframe"
>
</iframe>
```

```js
const Iframe = {
  mounted() {
    this.el.style.height = this.el.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+25+'px';
  }
}

export default Iframe;
```

My problem is this code only work when I refresh the page.

1. When I click the page link, then come to the page, mounted() function run but not resize iframe height. It doesn’t work!
2. When I press “CTRL + R” and refresh the page, mounted() function also run then resize the iframe height. It works.

Any idea?

Thanks.